# Facebook account kit xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, facebook-account-kit

I am developing an application. This is my first application that I develop in xamarin. I was asked to put account kit but the problem. I can not find the procedure to put account kit on cross Plaform Ios and android in xamarin
Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

There're Xamarin Facebook components: [Facebook iOS SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios) and [Facebook Android SDK](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid).

Install these components in the corresponding platforms, then use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to trigger the related action in the PCL.

**Related:**

*Instead of using components, you also can binding the native libraries by yourself, here're the related Xamarin official documentations on binding library:*

- [*Binding a Java Library*](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/)
- [*Binding iOS Libraries*](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)

Comment: Just a note, I do not believe account kit is within the Facebook Android/Ios SDKs for Xamarin. However, there is Facebook Graph API support which can be used with account kit which should at least help.